# File-field in Django admin not showing when upgraded Django to 3 from 2.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, console

Django admin file field is showing "loading" after upgrading Django to 3 from 2.1

[image]

The console shows the error

[image]

[image]

It was working fine when it was 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try** loading library file online if its loading from local.

**Try** wrap it with a function.

**Try** use the code in the end of the page to load it after the page loads.